# How to output detail message about 5.x.x error on Sendmail

Tags: centos, smtp, sendmail

I'm using Sendmail Version 8.14.4 on Centos 6.3.
sendmail.cf of the Sendmail is left default of CentOS.

Sendmail does not output detail response message like below.

```
Aug  8 21:44:44 localhost sendmail[5075]: u78CicQr005073: to=hogehoge@grandeur09.com, delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120005, relay=mail.grandeur09.com. [124.24.34.228], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
```

On the other hand, Postfix can output detail response like below.

```
Aug  8 21:43:40 localhost postfix/smtp[4993]: EA843120806: to=<hogehoge@grandeur09.com>, relay=mail.grandeur09.com[124.24.34.228]:25, delay=0.32, delays=0.01/0.01/0.28/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host mail.grandeur09.com[124.24.34.228] said: 550 5.1.1 <hogehoge@grandeur09.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

The below message is important for me.

```
User unknown in local recipient table (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Do you know how to output detail response message returned by downstream SMTP server?

I tried to raise log level, but it was useless.

Comment: Perhaps your question would be better asked at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [su]?  I don't see a question about programming here.

Comment: OK. thank you. I'll post this question to UNIX & Linux.